# HttpMessageNotWritableException when calling method wrapped in aspect with spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a rest endpoint that I wanted to dynamically wrap with aspect.
I register my method interceptor in a BeanFactoryPostProcessor

```
 final AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
    pointcut.setExpression("execution(%s * my.package..*(..)");
    final MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor = (MethodInterceptor) beanFactory.getBean("methodInterceptor");
    final DefaultPointcutAdvisor defaultPointcutAdvisor = new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, methodInterceptor);
    beanFactory.registerSingleton(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), defaultPointcutAdvisor);
```

And so far my methodInterceptor bean does only

```
 @Override
  public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable{
    return invocation.proceed();
}
```

But when I add it and call the endpoint I can see some ugly exception in the logs

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.IllegalStateException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.IllegalStateException) (through reference chain: my.package.MyEndpointReturnClass$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f5dc6da["advisors"]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor[1]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor["pointcut"]->org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut["pointcutExpression"]->org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl["underlyingPointcut"]->org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut["signature"]->org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern["returnType"]->org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AnyTypePattern["typeParameters"]->org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePatternList["start"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePatternList.getStart(TypePatternList.java:518) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
```

MyEndpointReturnClass contains just a bunch of @JsonProperty annotated fields. Strangely the result is correctly returned to the called, its just me who sees the error in the logs.
Without an aspect I dont have any exceptions

No idea what is going on and what is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that wrapping objects with aspects do create a proxy objects.
In my case, the aspect catched also a bean, that was returned in a response from rest endpoint (bad architecture decistion, but anyway...). Jackson cannot handle correctly a Spring AOP/CGLib proxy, and tries to serialize elements generated by proxy class and breaks...